# c++ pcre2_compile gets incomplete type

Tags: c++, pcre

[g++4.8.2, pcre2-10.31, linux] [c++ ~newbie]
I'm trying to learn how to use some simple calls to pcre2 from a c++ program.

```
#include <string>
#define PCRE2_CODE_UNIT_WIDTH 8
#include "pcre2.h"
int main()
{
  std::string xpattern = "(\\+|-)?[[:digit:]]+";
  int errorcode;
  PCRE2_SIZE *erroroffset = NULL;
  pcre2_code *code = pcre2_compile((const unsigned char *)xpattern.c_str(), PCRE2_ZERO_TERMINATED, 0, &errorcode, erroroffset, NULL); 
}
```

```
g++ -I/scratch_b/qa/tmp/pcre/include -g -Wall -o simple simpleregex2.cpp
simpleregex2.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
simpleregex2.cpp:9:15: warning: unused variable ‘code’ [-Wunused-variable]
   pcre2_code *code = pcre2_compile((const unsigned char *)xpattern.c_str(), PCRE2_ZERO_TERMINATED, 0, &errorcode, erroroffset, NULL); 
               ^
simpleregex2.cpp:9: error: undefined reference to 'pcre2_compile_8'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Thanks, I fixed the pointer problem, still get 'undefined reference'...?

Comment: According to [this API documentation](https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2api.html#SEC1) `pcre2_compile` returns a pointer, not a copy

Comment: While the code you show is a nice [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it doesn't match the error message you show. There aren't 15 lines in that snippet of codes, and the error is on line 15. Always show the error from the code you actually show.

Comment: Please, read API before posting. C APIs like this typically work with opaque structures, so you can only use them by pointer, not value. Hence "incomplete type" (before you even try to assign an expression of an incompatible type to that incomplete type). I'm voting to close this as being (A) incomplete in terms of the code shown and (B) caused by a simple typographic error, i.e. the missing asterisk.

Answer (score 1):

Got it, thanks all:
    g++ -I/scratch_b/qa/tmp/pcre//include -g -Wall simpleregex2.cpp  -o simple -Wl,-rpath,/scratch_b/qa/tmp/pcre//lib -L/scratch_b/qa/tmp/pcre//lib -lpcre2-8